Refresh dropdown options on HTML form embedded in modal dialog on Google Sheets after form submission
Seems like there are lots of questions regarding how to accomplish this here, but I haven't been able to implement anything that works for my case.
I have a HTML form in a modal dialog on Google Sheets.  This form is used to update names of jobs using textFinder.  (These names of jobs are used in multiple spreadsheets at the company and are sometimes concatenated with other values, such as to link jobs and individuals together for example.)
The first field is a dropdown for selecting the job name to update.  The dropdown pulls its values from a range on a Google spreadsheet.  The second field is a text field for inputting the new name.  After submission of the form, all instances of the original job name are replaced with the new name across multiple spreadsheets, including the original name in the spreadsheet range that populates the form dropdown.
All of this works properly.  Where I am stuck is in allowing people to make multiple changes in a row without closing the modal (or having it close automatically).  The dropdown does not update to display the new values.  What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using) and then a refresh of the form. I am not sure how to implement that function in my code here.  I know that it can be done with the withSuccesshandler function but I have not been able to get it to work.  Can someone help me out with this?
The code that applies is:
Code.js
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Manager Menu')
        .addItem('Update Job Name', 'updateNameModal')
        .addToUi();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
}
    
function updateNameModal() {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map( row => row[0] ); // get the name from each row
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("updateNameFile");
    html.dropdown = values;
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Update a Name Globally");
}

The above script creates the modal and defines the range for the dropdown.
HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css"
    />
    <style>
      .container {
          margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      }

      .input-Dropdown {

        width: 290px; 
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: left; 
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      }

      .input-Text {

        width: 290px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: left; 
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      }

      .custom-heading {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      
    <form id ="nameForm" onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter'">

    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Select a name from the list:<br><br>
    <select class="input-Dropdown" id="Current_Name"/>
    <? for(var i=1; i<dropdown.length; i++){ ?>
      <option><?= dropdown[i] ?></option>
    <?}?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    Change Name To:<br><br>
    <input class="input-Text" type="text" id="Updated_Name"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="action" onclick="submitNameUpdate();">Update</button>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close();">Close</button>
    </form>
    </div> 
    <script>
    function submitNameUpdate() {
       var current_name = document.getElementById("Current_Name").value;
       var updated_name = document.getElementById("Updated_Name").value;

       //Asynchronous 
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {
          window.alert("✔️ " +current_name+ " has been changed to " +updated_name+ " across the system.").servercommand();
        }).withFailureHandler(er => {
          alert(er);
        }).updateJobName(current_name, updated_name); // <-- updateJobName function exist on Code.gs, parameters are passed to that function
    }
  </script>
  </body> 
</html>

Code.js
function updateJobName(current_name, updated_name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let value1 = current_name;
  let value2 = updated_name;

  sheet.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(value1).replaceAllWith(value2);

The script above is run when the "Update" button is clicked and replaces the values in the dropdown.
Let me know if any more information is needed.  Thank you.

Can you provide your whole script?

Have done so now.

Thank you for replying. Your function updateJobName is your actual script?

Just a minute.   Let me see what I am missing.

When the button is clicked, submitNameUpdate captures the values.  updateJobName then completes the process, replacing values in A2:A on Sheet2.  I have other scripts that also use these values, but they are additional and do not affect the functionality at all.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed modification points as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to update the dropdown list when "Update" button is clicked.

Modification points:
Is your function updateJobName your current script? In your showing Javascript, it seems that updateJobName returns data. But, in your Google Apps Script, updateJobName returns no value. In order to achieve this, I think that it is required to return the updated values.
When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Javascript side:
First, in order to achieve your request The alert looks unprofessional. A modal on top of the modal?, as a simple method, jquery is used. So, please add the following 3 lines.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

And, in order to display What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using)..., please add the following tag in the HTML.
<div class="dialog" style="display: none;">What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using)...</div>

And also, please modify submitNameUpdate as follows.
From:
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {
  window.alert("✔️ " +current_name+ " has been changed to " +updated_name+ " across the system.").servercommand();
}).withFailureHandler(er => {
  alert(er);
}).updateJobName(current_name, updated_name);

To:
$(".dialog").dialog({
  modal: true,
  title: "sample title",
  buttons: {
    Ok: function () {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {
        var select = document.getElementById("Current_Name");
        select.innerHTML = "";
        data.forEach(e => {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = e;
          option.value = e;
          select.appendChild(option);
        });
        document.getElementById("Updated_Name").value = "";
        window.alert("✔️ " + current_name + " has been changed to " + updated_name + " across the system.").servercommand();
      }).withFailureHandler(er => {
        alert(er);
      }).updateJobName(current_name, updated_name);

      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

Google Apps Script side:
Please modify updateJobName as follows.
function updateJobName(current_name, updated_name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let value1 = current_name;
  let value2 = updated_name;
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(value1).replaceAllWith(value2);
  return sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(row => row[0]);
}

With the above modifications, when "Update" button is clicked, the dropdown list is updated with the new values.
Note:

I reflected the following reply in the above modification,

So the refresh part works with one exception. My original dropdown range is A2:A on Sheet2. After form is submitted, dropdown values display A1:A from Sheet 2.


Additionally, I was hoping for the form to display a confirmation message: What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using)... then refresh the form. The alert looks unprofessional. A modal on top of the modal?



Added:
About the following reply,

Regarding adding lines to Javascript side, where exactly should those lines be added?

The modified whole HTML is as follows.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .container {
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    .input-Dropdown {

      width: 290px;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    .input-Text {

      width: 290px;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    .custom-heading {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <form id="nameForm" onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter'">

      <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
      Select a name from the list:<br><br>
      <select class="input-Dropdown" id="Current_Name"/>
      <? for(var i=1; i<dropdown.length; i++){ ?>
      <option>
        <?= dropdown[i] ?>
      </option>
      <?}?>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    Change Name To:<br><br>
      <input class="input-Text" type="text" id="Updated_Name"/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <button class="action" onclick="submitNameUpdate();">Update</button>
      <button onclick="google.script.host.close();">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="dialog" style="display: none;">What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using)...</div>

  <script>
    function submitNameUpdate() {
      var current_name = document.getElementById("Current_Name").value;
      var updated_name = document.getElementById("Updated_Name").value;

      $(".dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "sample title",
        buttons: {
          Ok: function () {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {
              var select = document.getElementById("Current_Name");
              select.innerHTML = "";
              data.forEach(e => {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = e;
                option.value = e;
                select.appendChild(option);
              });
              document.getElementById("Updated_Name").value = "";
              window.alert("✔️ " + current_name + " has been changed to " + updated_name + " across the system.").servercommand();
            }).withFailureHandler(er => {
              alert(er);
            }).updateJobName(current_name, updated_name);

            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>


So the refresh part works with one exception.  My original dropdown range is A2:A on Sheet2.  After form is submitted, dropdown values display A1:A from Sheet 2.

Additionally, I was hoping for the form to display a confirmation message:  What I would really like to achieve is a confirmation message (instead of the alert that I am using)... then refresh the form.  The alert looks unprofessional.  A modal on top of the modal?

@Codedabbler Thank you for replying. About your additional 2 requests, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. And, pleaes modify your confirmation message to your actual situation.

Regarding adding lines to Javascript side, where exactly should those lines be added?

@Codedabbler Thank you for replying. About Regarding adding lines to Javascript side, where exactly should those lines be added?, I added the modified whole HTML. Please confirm it.

Yes.  That works perfectly except the issue I had in the first comment. So the refresh part works with one exception. My original dropdown range is A2:A on Sheet2. After form is submitted, dropdown values display A1:A from Sheet 2.  Dropdown now displays A1:A.  Previously it displayed A2:A. (I have a header in A1 on Sheet2).

So close...are you look at my last comment when you have a chance?

@Codedabbler Thank you for replying. About Dropdown now displays A1:A. Previously it displayed A2:A. (I have a header in A1 on Sheet2)., I have already modified in my answer. Please confirm the last row of updateJobName. I have already modified to return sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(row => row[0]);. Please confirm it again. If you cannot understand it, please tell me. At that time, please provide your whole script.

Everything is now working as desired.  Thank you for all your help.
